# Google Speech API Invalid Argument "Audio Content" Too long

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, google-speech-api

I've been getting some error when trying to send a batch of audio data to the Google speech api for transcribing. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't work, I get an error of the form:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mihaileric/Documents/Research/Ford Project/forddialogue/util/record_and_transcribe_audio.py", line 196, in <module>
    listen_for_speech()
  File "/Users/mihaileric/Documents/Research/Ford Project/forddialogue/util/record_and_transcribe_audio.py", line 163, in listen_for_speech
    transcribe_audio(filename)
  File "/Users/mihaileric/Documents/Research/Ford Project/forddialogue/util/record_and_transcribe_audio.py", line 57, in transcribe_audio
    for response in responses:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 366, in next
    return self._next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 357, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, Invalid 'audio_content': too long.)>`

The most relevant chunk of code is probably the following:

```
client = speech.SpeechClient()

# [START migration_streaming_request]
with io.open(audio_file, 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()

# In practice, stream should be a generator yielding chunks of audio data.
stream = [content]
requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=chunk)
            for chunk in stream)

config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=RATE,
    language_code='en-US')
streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(config=config)

# streaming_recognize returns a generator.
# [START migration_streaming_response]
responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)
print "Responses: ", responses
for response in responses: <-- FAILS HERE
    for result in response.results:
        print('Finished: {}'.format(result.is_final))
        print('Stability: {}'.format(result.stability))
        alternatives = result.alternatives
        for alternative in alternatives:
            print('Confidence: {}'.format(alternative.confidence))
            print('Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
```

`

The thing that confuses me is that the audio data that I send is not extremely long, never longer than ~15 sec. I use a sampling rate of 16000 on single channel audio, and the file written is ".wav". This also has been a difficult bug to find possible solutions for on Google, since it doesn't seem other people have had trouble with this. I would appreciate any leads on what I should look at for possible sources of error. Thanks!

Comment: Streaming recognize is for audio streams (such as microphone inputs to be recognized in realtime). If you have the audio file perhaps the (synchronous) recognize or the asynchronous recognize methods are what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response -- I actually am receiving input from my machine's microphone!

Comment: thanks for the clarification!  In this case you would want to replace the variable `stream` in the sample code with a generator that continues yielding small chunks of the audio data from the microphone.  It may be a good idea to divide the audio data into chunks of something like 4096 bytes each.